# laravel - cross join not returning all columns

Tags: php, sql, laravel

```
╔═══╦══════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║id            ║name         ║
╠═══╬══════════════╬═════════════╣
║   ║ 1            ║a1           ║
║   ║ 2            ║b1           ║
║   ║ 3            ║b2           ║
║   ║ 4            ║c1           ║
║   ║ 5            ║c2           ║
╚═══╩══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

This is my table in mysql

Executing this query in mysql:

```
select * from (select * from courses where name like 'a%') as t1 cross join (select * from courses where name like 'b%') as t2 cross join (select * from courses where name like 'c%') as t3
```

returns this:

[image]

However when I try to run it on larael to display the result, I get sth different.

This is how I am executing in laravel:

```
$posts = DB::select(DB::raw("select * from (select * from courses where name like 'a%') as t1 cross join (select * from courses where name like 'b%') as t2 cross join (select * from courses where name like 'c%') as t3"));
```

This is what `$posts` returns :

```
[{"id":4,"name":"c1"},{"id":4,"name":"c1"},{"id":5,"name":"c2"},{"id":5,"name":"c2"}]
```

Its only returning last two columns of the query I suppose, if we compare it to the original result as returned on mysql.

Any idea how to get the complete result?

Comment: What is the output of `DB::raw` without `DB::select` around it?

Comment: @Quezler its returning the query back! : 
select * from (select * from courses where name like 'a%') as t1 cross join (select * from courses where name like 'b%') as t2 cross join (select * from courses where name like 'c%') as t3

Comment: Try using proper parentheses around your sub-queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t3` overwrites the values of `t1` and `t2`. You have to use aliases:

```
select t1.id as t1_id, t1.name as t1_name,
    t2.id as t2_id, t2.name as t2_name,
    t3.id as t3_id, t3.name as t3_name
```

You should also use the [query builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries) instead of raw SQL.

Comment: Thanks.
Is there any particular disadvantage of using raw SQL? I find raw SQL to be more natural idk.

Comment: When you insert user input into the query, it's a lot harder to write insecure code with the query builder. Also, you can use the same PHP code for multiple databases (MySQL, SQLite etc.).

Comment: Is there anyway I can incorporate a where clause in this query? If i try adding it like this : select t1.id as t1_id, t1.name as t1_name,
    t2.id as t2_id, t2.name as t2_name,
    t3.id as t3_id, t3.name as t3_name(select * from courses where name like 'a%') as t1 cross join (select * from courses where name like 'b%') as t2 cross join (select * from courses where name like 'c%') as t3 where t1_name = 'test';

It throws an error "#1054 - Unknown column 't1_name' in 'where clause'

Comment: Use the column's original name: `where('t1.name', 'test')`